# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: ‘int’ and ‘str’ (python)

Tags: python

I am writing a small incremental game in python, and it pops up with an error when I try to run it (error in title). I would appreciate some help.

```
print("Farming complete! You earned "
   + str(((fullshark * shark_bite)
         + ((golden_shark * 5) * shark_bite) * int(farminglength)
         + " fish!")))
```

Comment: you can't concatenate str and int, and the message says, and as, I assume, you already know, given that you are using `str` on what appears to be a number. I imagine this is just a typo, and the parenthesis are in the wrong place?

Comment: Your code is bad (not really readable). Try to split in several line. The first line: calculate the the points, maybe split that in more lines. This will also help to find errors. In this case one of your `+` has one integer on left and a string on the right, but from your code we do not know the types of the variables.

Comment: You have `+ " fish"` inside the call to `str()` but it should be after it. Better still, use f-strings.

Comment: To njzk2, I am trying to get it to print that equation. That is why the whole equation is inside of parentheses and has a str in front.

Comment: Use a quoted string to print the equation.

Comment: To giacomo, thank you for the feedback. The farminglength variable is a user input, while all others are number variables.

Comment: Ok, it’s fixed. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when you try to add a string to a number, this is happening because you are doing too many things in 1 line of code, and the parenthesis are not setup correctly.

To see it more clearly I would suggest doing something like this:

```
calculate_fish = ((fullshark * shark_bite) + (golden_shark * 5) * shark_bite) * int(farminglength)
farming_complete_msg = "Farming complete! You earned {0} fish!".format(calculate_fish)
print(farming_complete_msg)
```

Not sure if the math in "calculate_fish" is exactly what you wanted (it was hard to know where the parenthesis were intended to be) but you can adjust it if its not what you need.

I hope it helps!